# Diagnosing cause of Windows 10 app crash?

Tags: windows-10, crash

Im trying to run an application on a w10 pro machine called Scrapebox.

The application is a main application along, which in turn can launch download an launch other mini applications, the mini applications can be launched from inside the main application, or stand alone.

The main application and most of the mini applications run fine, but some of the mini applications crash on launch. Ive been speaking to the developer / support team via their support portal and they have advised that because no crash log is being generated when the mini application crashes, that they believe the issue is caused by an anti virus or some of system / OS level process killing the application.

I dont believe its a hardware issue as the computer hardly breaks a sweat and usually always feels pretty snappy.

Ive tried adding an exception for the main application and mini application to the Anti Virus (Sophos) and also tried running the mini application as admin, but neither of these solve the issue, any ideas ?

Comment: Run Control Panel, Security and Maintenance,  Maintenance, Reliability History. What does that tell you, if anything, beyond the crashing app.

Comment: @John Thanks, that gives me some feedback, not sure what to make of it thought, see screenshot here : https://imgur.com/7RhUDUs

Comment: Scratch my last comment.. you gave me most of what is needed (probably).  Try finding a newer copy of.. and updating the copy of libea32.dll referenced in your apps directory (shown in the exception record).  You might even try renaming it and see if a better version gets picked up somewhere in your PATH..  Your error is access violation which means that memory was referenced that didn't exist.  Could be a bug in the app but probably something got fixed on the windows end for security reasons (SSL) and the DLL needs a new version.

Comment: Send the block of text to the App Vendor as that should help them.

Comment: Thanks @SeñorCMasMas - i tried deleting libea32.dll for the main app, re opened the main app the main app through an error saying it needed that file, re downloaded it and it worked fine. The mini app has its own libea32.dll file, tried deleting libea32.dll for the mini app im having trouble with, and re opening the mini app but it wont open without the libea32.dll in place.

Comment: @SeñorCMasMas Got it working !!!! I took the libea32.dll from the main app and copied and pasted it in the place of the mini app's libea32.dll  file, now the mini app works ! THANKS SO MUCH

Comment: WOOHOOO!  This makes me happy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try finding a newer copy of.. and updating the copy of libea32.dll referenced in your apps directory (shown in the exception record).

You might even try renaming it and see if a better version gets picked up somewhere in your PATH.

Your error is access violation which means that memory was referenced that didn't exist. Could be a bug in the app but probably something got fixed on the windows end for security reasons (SSL) and the DLL needs a new version.

Get a new copy of the DLL from the internet.  Try again.